# How do you invoke const integers in one function into another in C++ using pass by reference?

Tags: pass-by-reference

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void asknumber(int,int,int,int,int,int,int);
void getClassnumbers();

int main() {
    getClassnumbers();
    asknumber();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void asknumber(int &tests, int &projects, int &labs, int &attendance, 
int &max_test, int &max_projects, int &max_labs, int &max_attendance) {

    int min = 0; 
    getClassnumbers();
    cout << "Enter a number between 0 and " << max_test << ":";
    cin >> tests;

    while (tests > max_test || tests < min) {
        cout << "Invalid input. Enter a number between 0 and " << max_test << 
        ":";
        cin >> tests;
    }

    cout << "Enter a number between 0 and " << max_projects << ":";
    cin >> projects;
    while (projects > max_projects || projects < min) {
        cout << "Invalid input. Enter a number between 0 and " << max_projects 
        << ":";
        cin >> projects;
    }


    cout << "Enter a number between 0 and " << max_labs << ":";
    cin >> labs;
    while (labs > max_labs || labs < min) {
        cout << "Invalid input. Enter a number between 0 and " << max_labs << 
         ":";
        cin >> labs;
    }

    cout << "Enter a number between 0 and " << max_attendance << ":";
        cin >> attendance;
        while (attendance> max_attendance || attendance < min) {
        cout << "Invalid input. Enter a number between 0 and " << max_attendance << ":";
        cin >> attendance;
    }
}

void getClassnumbers() {
    int tests; int projects; int labs; int attendance;
    const int max_test = 4; const int max_projects = 5; const int max_labs = 7; const int max_attendance = 50;

    cout << "Enter number of tests: ";
    cin >> tests;
    cout << "Enter number of projects: ";
    cin >> projects;
    cout << "Enter number of labs: ";
    cin >> labs;
    cout << "Enter number of attendance days: ";
    cin >> attendance;
}
```

I was wondering how to properly use pass by reference for me to use the `cin` values entered in the function `getClassnumbers()` to be used in the `while` loops in the function `asknumber()` in order to compare them with the maximum values declared in `getClassnumbers()`?